# How to apply a border to a transparent image on a canvas?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, image-processing, canvas, konvajs

I'm working on transparent images with canvas in html5 and I would like to add borders.

The problem is that the property "Stroke" will not take into account the transparency of the image and will apply it as if it were a rect.

Example:

[image]

Of course, this image contains transparency.

I can get the result I want with imagemagick:

[image: Example border image with imagemagick]

I only use png images.
**I want to use the canvas in HTML to perform this operation.**
I use vue-konva but I can also stay on native canvas if you have solutions to offer to me ...

Answer (score 0):

Does this helps :

```
<rect x="10" y="10" width="100" height="100" stroke="blue" fill="purple"
       fill-opacity="0.5" stroke-opacity="0.8"/>
```

Comment: Thank you but it's not really what I want. Your code is to create a rect with a border.

I want to add a border to an image containing transparency.